# How to create documents and sub-documents at same time in Node Mongo DB mongoose Express App

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I'm getting below details from registration screen,
How can I create sub-documents in Node mongo express mongo app.
I'm new to node js and mongo db, not able to understand how to create
sub-documents from registration page (20+ fields getting from registration page, I give below schema with fewer fields)

```
{
    fullname: 'Some Name',
    // Sub document
    education: {
        degree: 'Graduation',
        college: 'Some College'
    },
    // Sub document
    questions: [
        { qns: 'Question 1', ans: 'Answer1' }
        { qns: 'Question 2', ans: 'Answer2' }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You mean sub-documents ?

Comment: Yes, will update the question

Comment: what is the challenge here ? Please explain what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I can create like this
{
    fullname: 'Some Name',
    degree: 'Graduation',
    college: 'Some College'
}

but not able to create sub documents

Comment: So your sub-documents are added into the schema or are they dynamic ?

Comment: That is what my question is, how to add sub documents to schema. sub documents are not dynamic only questions array having 4 fixed options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this!

```
    const Student = Schema({
        fullname:{
          type: String,
          required: false,
          default: ''
        },
        questions: [
          new mongoose.Schema({
            ans: {
              type: String,
              required: false,
              default: ''
            },
            que: {
              type: String,
              required: false,
              default: ''
            }
          })
        ]
    })
```